# How to update one cell's value, with the latest entry in a particular row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like to update one cell value, when change occur in a specified range.
e.g.: if I type in "asd" on WorkSheet1 anywhere within Range A1:A100
then on WorkSheet2 A1 would be updated to "asd"
After, if I type in "fgh" on WorkSheet1 anywhere within Range A1:A100
then on WorkSheet2 A1 would be updated again to "fgh" and so on...

Is there a simple VBA code to reach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an **event macro**.  This is an example.  Put this in the code area for `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, destn As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    Set destin = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
       destin.Value = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

whenever a change is made to the range being monitored, the latest value is copied to the destination cell.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Just what I needed :)